# How to remove problem with AWS Amplify and S3 dependency

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

for my uni assigmnet I am developing and android app (I am newbie) that will store user recordings on cloud storage (it would be expanded in future).
I am using Aws amplify for creating users, and tried to send made in app recordings to S3 database.
Problem is when i add s3 storage dependency to my build.gradle some Amplify features stop working.

```
Amplify.DataStore.query(User.class,
                    allPosts -> {
                        while (allPosts.hasNext()) {
                            User user = allPosts.next();
                            this.currentUser = user;
                            Log.i("app", "data download compleated for user: " + user.getName() + " " + user.getSurname());
                        }
                    },
                    failure -> Log.e("app", "Query failed.", failure)
            );
```

this code is supposed to get user data from DataStore for naming recordings, but when I add

`implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-storage-s3:1.17.4'`

to build.gradle I've got this error:

*DataStoreException{message=Failed to start DataStore., cause=DataStoreException{message=Timed out while starting to observe storage changes., cause=null, recoverySuggestion=There is a possibility that there is a bug if this error persists. Please take a look at*

I've found this on github:

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/issues/1163

post ends with "the issue has now been magically resolved. Unfortunately, I don't know exactly what was the causes"

this is my amplify config:

```
Amplify.addPlugin(new AWSDataStorePlugin(provider));
Amplify.addPlugin(new AWSApiPlugin());
Amplify.addPlugin(new AWSCognitoAuthPlugin());
Amplify.addPlugin(new AWSS3StoragePlugin());

Amplify.configure(getApplicationContext());
```

when i delete dependency and Amplify.addPlugin(new AWSS3StoragePlugin()) then my app works fine and query is working as intended and User object is created.

my schema:

```
type User @model @auth(rules: [{allow: owner, operations: [create, delete, update]}]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  surname: String
  phoneno: AWSPhone
  recording: [Recording] @connection(name: "UserRecordings")
}

type Recording @model @auth(rules: [{allow: private}]) {
  id: ID!
  date: AWSDateTime
  user: User @connection(name: "UserRecordings")
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure... this is a tough one. Which version of the amplify-cli are you using? `amplify version`

Comment: version is 4.50.0